# In VAR model, can I include not-granger-causing variables in impulse response anaysis?

Tags: vector-autoregression, granger-causality, impulse-response

In a VAR model, I have 6 endogenous variables(X: dependent, others: independent)

Having run Granger Causality test, I found that only 2 independent variables granger cause X.

Can I include other 3 insignificant variables when plotting Impulse Response Function?

I cannot find any paper about this.

Comment: Your terminology is confusing. An independent variable cannot be endogenous, and an endogenous variables cannot be independent.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding plotting the IRF, you can do it for all dependent variables in the model. So if you think a variable belongs in the model, you can plot its IRF.

Also, I find your terminology confusing. An independent variable cannot be endogenous, and an endogenous variable cannot be independent.